# Undefinex index of POST from Ajax jQuery array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo

Im trying to insert the info from the array into my database. The problem im having is first of all that i am getting undefined index of $_POST['Person'], $_POST['Color_name'], $_POST['Opinion'] from the php.

The second issue is that i would like to use dataType: "json"; in my Ajax jQuery but my data is not reaching the php file if i use it.

What i have tried so far is to json stringify my return data in the get_data function without any success. I also tried decoding the data in the php but since it's getting undefined index i am guessing there has to be some work done in the jQuery.

This is the array the get_data() function returns

```
{Person: "James", Color_name: "blue", Opinion: "Looks good"}
{Person: "James", Color_name: "green", Opinion: "Looks ok"}
{Person: "Rebecka", Color_name: "blue", Opinion: "Looks bad"}
{Person: "Rebecka", Color_name: "black", Opinion: "Looks very bad"}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <ul data-person="James">
    <li data-color_opinion="blue">Looks good</li>
    <li data-color_opinion="green">Looks ok</li>
  </ul>
  <ul data-person="Rebecka">
    <li data-color_opinion="blue">Looks bad</li>
    <li data-color_opinion="black">Looks very bad</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
function get_data() {
  var data = [];
  $.each($('ul'), function(i, el) {
    $.each($(el).find("[data-color_opinion]"), function(j, child) {
      let person = $(el).data('person');
      let color_name = $(child).data('color_opinion');
      let opinion = $(child).text();
      data.push({ Person: person, ColorName: color_name, Opinion: opinion });
    });
  });
  return data;
};
console.log(get_data())

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url:'colors.php',
data:get_data´(),
success: function(data) {
  console.log(data);
}
});
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$servername = "servername";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

$person = $_POST['Person'];
$color_name = $_POST['Color_name'];
$opinion = $_POST['Opinion'];


try {
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=DB_NAME", $username, $password);
 $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
 $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);


 $sql = "INSERT INTO colors (person, color_name, opinion)
     VALUES ($person, $color_name, $opinion)";

$db->exec($sql);
echo "New records created successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
$db = null;

 ?>
```

Comment: you still have unquoted string values and as per your deleted previous post https://stackoverflow.com/q/50086662/1415724

Comment: `data:get_data´(),` why is there a `´` after the function name? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: this IMHO, qualifies as a repost. You should have kept your previous question open.

Comment: I think problem is here `$_POST['Person']`. You are sending a nested array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `$_POST['Person'];` because all the javascript objects are in an outer array and `get_data()` returns the whole array

Try something like:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'colors.php',
  data: {items : get_data()},
        // ^^ items contains an array
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Then in php

```
$items = $_POST['items'];// is array of sub arrays

foreach($items as $item){
   $person = $item['Person'];
    // get the other values and do a query within each iteration of this loop
}
```

Comment: this is only a partial answer; you missed something for the mysql/values as I mentioned [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50087506/undefinex-index-of-post-from-ajax-jquery-array#comment87190830_50087506).

Comment: or should I also post a partial answer in regards to that? ^

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner what quotes are you referring to?

Comment: the query has string values which are unquoted.

Comment: I decided to post a wiki answer for a few reasons. I don't want rep from that. If you decide to upgrade yours, then I'll delete mine.

Comment: Works for me. At least this part gives OP access to the arrays

Comment: sure, up until you setup a database ;-) but I'll upvote.

Comment: Should really be paremterizing the query also

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you this works perfectly. I noticed something weird. When im adding dataType: "JSON", to my ajax jquery the php still works but the success function(data) is not returning anything? Got any idea there?

Comment: I don't see where you echo any json in the php. The `dataType` is for what is expected to be returned from server. If no json is sent back then success will not fire if you tell jquery to expect it

Answer (score 2):

Besides the other answer, this `VALUES ($person, $color_name, $opinion)` contains string values that need to be quoted.

```
VALUES ('$person', '$color_name', '$opinion')
```

However, that is open to an sql injection; use a prepared statement.

Comment: curious why this wasn't upvoted though. It's not as if I'll be making any rep from this.